# Changing color, highlight, background size of a ListBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

[image: https://i.imgur.com/2LTdcR2.png]

So I've searched around and managed to highlight the values in my `ListBox`, but I'm trying to increase the font size for the text inside the `ListBox` but it results in the following image as attached:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem

    e.DrawBackground()

    If ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString().Contains("*") Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, e.Bounds)
    End If

    e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Black, New System.Drawing.PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
```

I've tried messing with the "e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y" to increase the rectangle/size of the highlighted value but nothing seemed to work.

How does one allow the highlighted rectangle increase according to the font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the [DrawMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.DrawMode);k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) of a `ListBox` control to [OwnerDrawVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.DrawMode);k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) or you change the Font size after the control handle has been created (i.e. after it has already processed the `WM_MEASUREITEM` message), you need to *manually* set the [ItemHeigh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.itemheight?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ItemHeight);k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) property to the new Font height.

The `ItemHeight` property is set subscribing the `ListBox` [MeasureItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.MeasureItem);k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) event and setting the [`MeasureItemEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.measureitemeventargs?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) `e.ItemHeight` property.

Also, if you change the Font size *on the fly*, you also need to force the `WM_MEASUREITEM` message to be re-sent to the `ListBox` control, otherwise the Items Bounds will not be updated.
In other words, when the `DrawItem` event is raised, the [`DrawItemEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawitemeventargs?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) `e.Bounds` property will report wrong measures.

A way to force the `ListBox` control to re-measure its Items bounds, is to set `ListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal` and immediatly resetting it back to `OwnerDrawVariable`. This causes the `WM_MEASUREITEM` message to be processed again.

```
listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal
listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
listBox1.Update()
```

Here I'm using the `Font.Height` to measure the current `ItemHeight` in the `MeasureItem` event, because it rounds up the measure. You could use [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [Font.GetHeight()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.getheight(v=vs.110).aspx); you'll end up with the same measure, but rounded down.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem

    Dim ItemForeColor As Color
    Dim ItemBackColor As Color

    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit

    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        ItemForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.HighlightText)
        ItemBackColor = If(ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString().Contains("*"), Color.Red, Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight))
    Else
        ItemForeColor = ListBox1.ForeColor
        ItemBackColor = If(ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString().Contains("*"), Color.Red, ListBox1.BackColor)
    End If

    Using TextBrush As New SolidBrush(ItemForeColor)
        Using ItemBrush As New SolidBrush(ItemBackColor)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ItemBrush, e.Bounds)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString(), ListBox1.Font, TextBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
        End Using
    End Using
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MeasureItem(sender As Object, e As MeasureItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MeasureItem
    e.ItemHeight = ListBox1.Font.Height
End Sub
```

Test it resizing the Font:

```
ListBox1.Font = New Font(ListBox1.Font.FontFamily, ListBox1.Font.SizeInPoints + 2, ListBox1.Font.Style, GraphicsUnit.Point)
ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal
ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
ListBox1.Height = '[OriginalHeight]
ListBox1.Update()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I've tried using the solution you suggested but it did not seem to work, could it be because I'm using 'OwnerDrawFixed'?

Comment: @LimYX  Yes. Setting `OwnerDrawFixed`, the Item size is set to a, well, fixed measure. Change it to `OwnerDrawVariable`.

Comment: Right that makes more sense. Mmm it still doesn't seem to be working, how is `ListBox_DrawItem` getting the information from `e.ItemHeight` in this case? Sorry for the excessive questions, just trying to understand more so I won't have to rely on others next time I have problems.

Also, I added `Handles ListBox1.DrawItem` behind the `ListBox1_DrawItem` method. Do I have to do something similar for `ListBox1_MeasureItem`?

Comment: @LimYX  No problem. First of all, have you subscribed the events? Just copying the code won't do it. Set a breakpoint inside the `MeasureItem` event and see that it's triggered. About the question: when the `DrawMode` is set to `OwnerDrawVariable`, each Item can have it's own size. The `MeasureItem` event collects these measures, allowing to set the `ItemHeight` using the `e.ItemHeight` property. This is reflected in the `DrawItem` event `e.Bounds` property. But this happens when the `ListBox` control first processes the `WM_MEASUREITEM` message (or when it's forced to re-process it).

Comment: @LimYX  If you have problems adapting this code to yours, just update your question with the code you have modified and we'll fix it.

Comment: Mmmm I didn't modify the code too muchas there's plenty of syntax that I'm not too sure on that I'm slowly trying to google and understand, I merely added the `Handles ListBox1.DrawItem`.Also, what do you mean by subscribing to events? Does adding `Handles ListBox1.DrawItem` considered subscribing to the event? Also, tried what you mentioned and added a breakpoint to the `MeasureItem` event, did not seem to be triggered.

Comment: @LimYX  You better check in the Designer → Property Window → Events of your `ListBox1` that both `ListBox1_DrawItem` and `ListBox1_MeasureItem` events are registered. If the debugger doesn't stop in the `MeasureItem` event handler, it's not registered (the event is raised when you first load the Form, before it's shown). Open the ComboBox and choose the corresponding event. Verify that your old `ListBox1_DrawItem` is not the selected event. Also, see that the `ListBox` `DrawMode` is actually set to `OwnerDrawVariable`.