# how to change color background on any item in list box based on a program condition using vb.net windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

How can I set a custom color for ListBox’s selected item background, as well as a Display Value bigger then 50?

This my code for binding list box with a dataset, where tb is a table with filled data from database:

```
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = tb.Columns(2).ColumnName
        ListBox1.ValueMember = tb.Columns(0).ColumnName
        ListBox1.DataSource = tb
```

Comment: You would have to custom draw it with OwnerDraw property to true and use the DrawItem event.

Comment: You could also opt for a ListView control, which has this feature already available: each Item can have its own BackColor and ForeColor

Comment: can i bind list view to data table  ?

Comment: Ah, nope, not directly. If you want to use a ListBox, set its `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawVariable` (or `OwnerDrawFixed`, depending on the result you're looking for). Here's a VB.Net example (`OwnerDrawVariable`): [Changing color, highlight, background size of a ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731483/7444103).