# ListBox DrawItem repeated drawing text overlays

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a listbox which, based on some criteria, I draw the text in different colours.

However, as the .DrawItem event is called repeatedly the text becomes blurry. I believe this is because the text isn't being draw over the exact same pixels so the text basically layers up.

Screenshots below showing behaviour:

Initial draw:

[image: Initial Draw]

After subsequent draws:

[image: Repeated Draws]

I do the drawing like this:

```
Private Sub ListBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox.DrawItem

    e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox.Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Red, New PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))

End Sub
```

I've tried also using all options for `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint`.

Any ideas how I can avoid this behaviour? When `.DrawMode = Normal` this isn't an issue.

Comment: You forgot to call `e.DrawBackground()`. Unless you want to paint your own background. In that case, use `e.Graphics.FillRectangle()` (before drawing the text, of couse). The items' Text should be rendered with [TextRenderer.DrawText.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer). Otherwise, set `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit` and `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` in `e.Graphics.DrawString`. You should also add `If e.Index < 0 Then Return`

Comment: Well, here's an example in VB.Net: [Changing color, highlight, background size of a ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731483/7444103)

Comment: Doh! I was drawing the background only once on the -1 index, not every time. How silly. Feel free to make as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!