# ListBox draw size does not change with change to larger font size

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, listbox

When I increase the font size in my ListBox, the larger text strings get vertically clipped because the item draw rectangle size (spacing) does not increase with the font size. Each lower line of text overlays the previous line of text so that only the tops of letters show in larger font sizes.

Everything works fine with `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` if I don't change the font sizes. Smaller-than-normal fonts display properly. It's only the larger fonts that get clipped. I changed to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable` and added a MeasureItem event handler to measure the larger font size explicitly, but that did not work either.

What am I missing? Thank you.

UPDATE: I provided working code below based on @Jimi's examples in the links he provided in his comments. I was missing the idea that the MeasureItem event runs only once (or when necessary) and not for each drawn item. Thus, you must manually trigger a new MeasureItem event when you change the font size in the ListBox. The trick to generating the event is to flip the `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable` to Normal and back.

```
  listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
  listBox1.DrawItem += DrawItemHandler;
  listBox1.MeasureItem += MeasureItemHandler;

  private void MeasureItemHandler(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e) {
    // must measure the height to allow for user font size changes
    var listBox = (ListBox) sender;
    e.ItemHeight = listBox.Font.Height;
  }

  public void DrawItemHandler(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
      // prepare text and colors for drawing here
      //
      using (var bgbrush = new SolidBrush(bgcolor)) {
        using (var fgbrush = new SolidBrush(fgcolor)) {
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bgbrush, e.Bounds);
          e.Graphics.DrawString(logEntry.EntryText, e.Font, fgbrush, e.Bounds);
        }
      }

      e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }


  private void fontUpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // To increase size alone, use the original font family
    var size = listBox1.Font.Size;
    if (size < 32) {
      // set the new font size, register it with the list box, and then
      // flip the draw mode back and forth to trigger a MeasureItem event.
      // The measure event will recalculate the bounds for all items in the box.
      listBox1.Font = new Font(listBox1.Font.FontFamily, size + 1);
      listBox1.Height = listBox1.Font.Height;
      listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal;
      listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
      listBox1.Invalidate();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you referring to the problem with a Font changed *on-the-fly* described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731483/7444103)? You could also draw your items as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60589434/7444103) (with a custom ListBox control)

Comment: _When I increase the font size in my ListBox_ - Where do you do that?  - The control can't know what you do int the DrawItem  event. You can try to set the Control's Font to the maximum size needed. - Also setting the item height to font.height will not leave any slack. I would first just set the font and let the system size the items automatically.

Comment: BTW, you're leaking two Brushes per item drawn, `FillRectangle()` overwrites  `e.DrawBackground();` (you should draw two different backgrounds based on the selection status, as shown in the example, or just draw the standard background which will use the pre-defined Colors) and `e.DrawFocusRectangle();` is in the wrong place.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your links and examples; I didn't find them in my original search. TaW, I'm sorry for not posting the fontUpClick handler code in the OP; it is there now. Jimi, the code works now, but only with `OwnerDrawVariable` -> Normal and back. I don't need variable list items, so I tried `OwnerDrawFixed` to Normal and back, but that failed. Is there a way of triggering the MeasureItem event directly? Is it important/helpful to use Fixed instead of Variable if all items are the same size? Thank you.

Comment: If you plan on changing the Font at run-time, you're most probably better off with `OwnerDrawVariable`. The Items' rendering is the same. -- You could send a `WM_MEASSUREITEM` message, filling a [MEASUREITEMSTRUCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-measureitemstruct) structure. But the .Net control performs other actions when the DrawMode is set: it recreates the ListBox Handle, it clears the internal cache, sets the PreferredSize and causes the Parent to generate Layout events. Setting the same property twice seems more convenient.

Comment: @Jimi, one last question - where can I begin to learn the things that you know about WinForms? I have Sells and Petzhold books, but they are not at your level. Thank you.

Comment: I'm a what?! ... Petzhold? No, seriously. What I know quite simply comes from what I've read, from the people I work/worked with, from those who write here. One has just commented in this post, TaW. Many others. I have to mention Hans Passant (`nobugz` in the MSDN Forums), he's the one you can compare to Petzhold without causing a disturbance in the Force :).

Comment: Yes, Hans is another one whose knowledge runs deep. You both display knowledge (from somewhere) that is not easily found in the usual places. Thank you again, you helped me a lot. Until next time...